# How to load specific version of assembly from GAC

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, gac

For testing purpose I like to load a specific version of an DLL assembly from GAC. However, my program always load the latest version - I think driven by Policy Assemblies.

```
var dll = Assembly.Load("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342");
Console.WriteLine(dll.ToString());
```

Output:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
```

Even though I specify version "4.121.1.0" in strong name it loads version "4.122.1.0". Is there a way to force a specific version?

Result from `fuslogvw.exe` as requested in comment:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (29.06.2017 @ 11:24:15) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Programs\Tools\ConnectionTester_x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Programs/Tools/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ConnectionTester_x64.exe
Calling assembly : ConnectionTester_x64, Version=1.0.353.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Publisher policy file is found at C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\v4.0_4.122.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.config.
LOG: Publisher policy file redirect is found: 4.121.1.0 redirected to 4.122.1.0.
LOG: ProcessorArchitecture is locked to MSIL.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\v4.0_4.122.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

It looks as expected, saying

> Publisher policy file redirect is found: 4.121.1.0 redirected to 4.122.1.0.

but I like to bypass it.

Version 4.121.1.0 is installed in GAC:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>gacutil /l Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.18020
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 3

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

Comment: Use fuslogvw.exe, log all binds.  Show the trace in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant, added log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably will have to bypass the publisher policy.
Add to your application configuration file to the dependentAssembly

```
<publisherPolicy apply="no" />
```

more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection)

Comment: `<publisherPolicy apply="no" />` is working, however setting `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` did not change anything.