# Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.48.0.0 after upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I have an application built in Asp.net, we upgraded the oracle database to 19c "where we were working on oracle 11g", first give us the below error:

> Could not install package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework, Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

After searching I found **the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.5.0 requires .NET Framework version 5.**

Anyway, I upgrade the target framework for all projects from **4.5** to **4.7.2** and that issue didn't appear anymore.

After that, I tried to install **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.13.0**  and it was installed successfully but when I try to login "need to connect to the database" it give me the error message:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.48.0.0

I tried to clean the solution and rebuild it, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `.dll` assemblies are loaded either from Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or from folder where your `.exe` is located. **The files from GAC take precedence!**

Check which `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` you have installed, you can use the [Global Assembly Cache Tool (gacutil.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool).

```
gacutil /l | findstr Oracle
```

Have a careful look at the Policy Files, they may redirect to a newer version.

If you need to load a specific version of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` see [How to load specific version of assembly from GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818069/how-to-load-specific-version-of-assembly-from-gac)

You can check the file and version of loaded `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` with

```
connection.GetType().Assembly.Location
connection.GetType().Assembly.FullName
```

You may also check [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) to see which client version works with your database:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. anyway, the "fullname" return the  below: "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"

Comment: I'm wondering because I'm working on pl/SQL developer where I connect correctly to the server "Oracle 19c" also I have on my PC "oracle 11g" and also connect correctly, but when I run the application it didn't connect correctly to the database where I update the framework and the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Comment: "SQL Developer" or "PL/SQL Developer"? "SQL Developer is Java/JDBC based and does not use any of these drivers. PL/SQL Developer may bypass Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and uses the core library `oci.dll` directly.

Comment: So, your application uses the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` version 12.1

Comment: I'm using "PL/SQL Developer" 32bit on my PC.

Comment: So I can't upgrade the "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"? because the "PL/SQL Developer" used 32bit where my oracle on my PC is  "Oracle 11g 32bit"

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess works for both, 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your target framework to .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later is the fix. No need to use an old version of the package.

[image]

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Comment: Thank you for your response, anyway I upgrade the framework to"4.6.1, 4.7.2" in order and then update the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to "19.13.0, 21.5.0" in order, and that didn't fix my issue.