Connect to Multiple versions of Mongo Db with one client C#
I have an application written in C# that read and write to two different MongoDb. Each Mongo db runs a different version (5.0.9 & 3.2.22) and I am not in a position to update either of these database to be the same version. Is there a way I can use my custom Mongo Client to access these 2 databases without having to worry about compatibility issue of the Mongo.Driver?
I read somewhere they are talking about using 2 assemblies in the project but it did not work as both versions of Mongo.Driver & Mongo.Bson need to be installed.
<configuration>
     <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.1.4791" newVersion="1.7.1.4791" />
        </dependentAssembly>
     </<assemblyBinding>
</configuration>

My Mongo client currently looks like this:
public class RepositoryClient : IRepositoryClient
{
    private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;
    private readonly string _database; 

    public RepositoryClient(IMongoClient mongoClient, string database)
    {
        _mongoClient = mongoClient;
        _database = database;
    }

    public T Find<T>(string collection, string id)
    {
        return GetCollection<T>(collection).Find(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", id)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string collection)
    {
        return _mongoClient.GetDatabase(_database).GetCollection<T>(collection);
    }
}


I guess you have to load the assembly which works with your MongoDB version, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818069/how-to-load-specific-version-of-assembly-from-gac

if you have 2 different db versions, then these databases have different connection string?

unless I'm missing some details, you should find the latest driver that support server 3.2, this driver will support server 5.0 too
